# Google translate free api resposne to JSON Array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

I'm working on a simple API in ruby on rails, which will connect with Google translate API (using the simple trick to get a response for free) and process the output.

My request looks like i.e.:

> https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=es&dt=t&q=build

and responses I'm getting from Google server is as follows (can't get a json formatted response, as setting client to 'p' no longer works)

> [[["construir","build",,,1]],,"en"]

In java I can easily process that response by creating a JSONArray object, however I can't find a way to do so in my ruby on rails app.

I'm using rest-client to make a request

```
@response=RestClient.post('http://myrequestblabla')
@jsonArray = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

and last line fails with

> A JSON text must at least contain two octets!

Is there anyway to process a response like that? Ideally to break it into JSONArray, but will be happy to see any neat solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Give the expected JSON output for the example you gave, since we may not know what Java's JSONArray does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use YAML module to parse this string. First insert null values between commas so the string will look like this:

```
[[["construir","build",null,null,1]],null,"en"]
```

Regexp the string by `gsub` and use `load` method of YAML module:

```
require 'yaml'
str = RestClient.post('http://myrequestblabla')
YAML::load(str.gsub(/(?<=,),/,'nil,'))
```

You will get an array `[[["construir", "build", nil, nil, 1]], nil, "en"]`